# Lambda Expression "not working properly"

Tags: angular, typescript, lambda

I'm having troubles assigning a value to an array in a *Observable* in a *Lambda* expression.

I have a class with this attribute:

```
usuarios: Usuario[];
```

I'm injecting a *Http* service.

I have a function with the following:

```
getUsuarios(): Usuario[] {

    this._http.get("http://localhost:3000/db").map(data => data.json()).subscribe(data => {
      this.usuarios = data["Usuarios"];
      console.log(this.usuarios);
    });

    console.log(this.usuarios);

    return this.usuarios;
  }
```

For some reasong, tho, in the console, with the first *console log* (the one within the lambda expression) shows the data perfectly.

But if I console log again, this time outside the lambda expression, `this.usuarios` is empty (*undefined*).

Why is that happening?

Comment: The http.get function is async, so the getUsuarios() returns its result before the http call completes, that's why it returns null. You probably want to return the observable instead of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed working properly, the expect console output should be:

`undefined`
`...some data`

The reason is that the http makes an asynchronous call meaning the first console.log() is not executed until you receive a response from the http request.
The 2nd console.log() is not within the same scope as the http request so it gets executed first. You can read more information related to your question [here](http://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2016/03/14/wrapping-your-head-around-async-programming/).

Comment: Is there any way to know when the async execution is completed? Something like the _await_ operator in C#.

Comment: When the async execution is completed this gets executed:
`.subscribe(data =>{ // here you can do something with your data.})`

Comment: Okay, just one more silly question. If I don't subscribe the _Observable_, is the http request still sent? I mean, I'll get a response back from the server but nothing will happen because I don't subscribe the _Observable_, right? I'll hold in the response within that _Observable_, right? That's what I mean. Or is it sent as soon as I do a subscription for that _Observable_? I don't know if I explained myself good-enough.

Comment: Not silly question at all. Well observables can be a bit tricky, we got 2 types, a hot observable and a cold observable. http.post (and get, put, delete, etc) returns a cold Observable ("..its underlying producer is created and activated during subscription"). So yes it is sent as soon as you do a subscription for that Observable. Feel free to read more about it [here.](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339#.tofgfsou4)